# How can I make functions from one module directly available in others using Typescript / node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this Javascript code running under node.js. I declare functions in more than one module and use an extend utility so the are available in others modules:

```
// File: util.js:
var Util = function () {
    this.doTask1 = function(name) { return 9; };
}
module.exports = new Util();

// File: base.js:
var util    = require('../../Utils/util.js');
var helpers = require('../../Utils/helpers.js');
var AdminBase = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.doTask2 = function(name) { return 99; };
}
module.exports = helpers.extend({}, util, new AdminBase());

// File: page.js:
var base = require('../Common/base.js');
var Page = function () {
   base.doTask1()
   base.doTask2()

// File: helpers.js
var extend = function (target) {
   var sources = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
   sources.forEach(function (source) {
      for (var prop in source) {
         target[prop] = source[prop];
      }
   });
   return target;
};
module.exports.extend = extend;
```

I now want to do the same using Typescript and I need some help. So far I understand that I need to code the importing of the modules like this:

```
// File: util.ts
module Util {
   export function doTask1(name) { return 9; };
}
export = Util;

// File: base.ts
import util = require('../../Utils/util');
import helpers = require('../../Utils/helpers.js');
var AdminBase = function () {
   var self = this;
   this.doTask2 = function(name) { return 99; };
}
module.exports = helpers.extend({}, util, new AdminBase());

// File: page.js:
import base = require('../Common/base.js');
var Page = function () {
   base.doTask1()
   base.doTask2()
```

I am getting confused about how to code this so that I can access the doTask1() 
and doTask2() functions in the same way as I was doing for when I was using the first method.

Can someone give me advice and let me know how I can handle the exporting of functions so I can access these in the same way as I was doing before.

Note that what I don't want is to have to be coding:

```
util.doTask1()
base.doTask2()
```

as this starts to become confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do

```
base.doTask1()
base.doTask2()
```

You need to export doTask1/doTask2 from base i.e.

```
// File: base.ts
import util = require('../../Utils/util');
import helpers = require('../../Utils/helpers.js');

export var doTask1 = util.doTask1;
export var doTask2 = function(name) { return 99; };
```